# How to justify the approximation ratio of this deterministic algorithm.(Weighted MAX-k-Cut)

Tags: algorithm, approximation, weighted

The weighted MAX-k-CUT problem asks for the maximum-weighted cut in a weighted undirected graph.
Suppose now each vertex is one-by-one greedily assigned to the group that can maximize the total weight of new cuts.
How to know the approximation rate of the deterministic algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 1/2. This particular algorithm can be obtained by applying the [method of conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_conditional_probabilities) to the randomized approximation that choose the assignment of each node independently and uniformly at random, which obtains 1/2 of the total edge weight in expectation and hence at least 1/2 of OPT.

An example where the ratio is 1/2 + ε can be obtained by taking K<sub>2,n</sub> with unit edge weights, adding an infinitestimally costed edge between the two vertices on one side and forcing the algorithm to consider them first.